# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'htmx'

Tags: python, django, django-views, htmx

Hi just looking for some help at solving this error in Django whilst trying to call a view that to accept a htmx request. The final result is to display a popup Modal of images from a Gallery when a thumbnail is clicked.

HTMX installed via script in head.

View

```
    if request.htmx:
        slug = request.GET.get('slug')
        context = {'pictures': Media.objects.filter(slug=slug)}
        return render(request, 'main/gallery-detail.html', context=context)

    context = {'objects_list': Albums.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'main/gallery.html', context=context)
```

Relevant html with the button to open gallery of images.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" hx-post="{{ request.path }}?slug={{ img.slug }}" hx-target="#modal">
                {{ img.slug }}</a>
{% endfor %}

<div id="modal">{% include "main/gallery-detail.html" %}</div>
```

Comment: What is `if request.htmx:` supposed to do?

Comment: To me, it was self explanatory and would take the htmx request from the template? I'm using this code here as I am learning HTMX at the moment. 
https://www.andytwoods.com/django-htmx-modal-popup-loveliness/

Comment: Looks like you did not installed/used `django-htmx` correctly.

Comment: Yea, literally just realised. Doh!

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Answer (score 2):

This error mostly occurs if you haven't included django-htmx in the settings.py.

Try making the below changes and see if it works :

1. Add "django_htmx.middleware.HtmxMiddleware" to the MIDDLEWARE.
2. Add "django_htmx" to the INSTALLED_APPS.